# How to get the index value of a character from a string in Python?

Tags: string, loops, python-3.x

How to read the index value of a specific character (say '**+**') from a string without using any function. They told me to do this using for loop. (Home work, I am not allowed to use homework tag due to low reputation)
I was doing this:

`S = input()
    for position in range(0,len(S)):
       if S[position] == '+':
          print(S[position])`
What I am getting as output is `+` sign itself instead of its index.
Thankyou!

Comment: From the help center: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @PRISONER I am new to programming, i was doing this `inputString = input()
for position in range(0,len(S)): 
   if inputString[position] == '+':` Somehow I was told to print the index value of '+' sign, but I was not understanding, I was using the `inputString[position] == '+'` but it was printing the '+' sign instead of its index. Oh, my lack of knowledge and practice, thanks..I figured it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `-1` to a variable. And add `1` to that variable for each iteration. And print out the value of the variable when the value of `i` (iterator) is equal to `+`

```
>>> s = "foo+bar"
>>> x = -1
>>> for i in s:
        x = x + 1
        if i == '+':
            print(x)


3
```

By defining a separate function.

```
>>> def index(s):
        x = -1
        for i in s:
            x = x + 1
            if i == '+':
                return x


>>> index('foo+bar')
3
>>> index('+foobar')
0
>>> index('foobar+')
6
```

And your code works fine for me. You just need to print the `position` instead of `S[position]`

```
>>> s = input()
foo+
>>> for pos in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[pos] == '+':
            print(pos)


3
```

Comment: :D Thanks again! Its obviously due to my carelessness!

Comment: @Vivek We are humans :-)

Comment: hmm...........       :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `position` is the index, while `S[position]` is the character at that position.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` is the built-in and efficient way to iterate through the indexes and contents of a sequence.

```
def index(text, char):
  for i, c in enumerate(text):
    if c == char:
        return i
```